# android listview refresh

Tags: android, listview, refresh, sd-card

hello every one
i want to refresh my listview after adding or removing any data.. the adapter is from the SDcard how can i do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this code after your data are
 change..

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **notifyDataSetChanged()** of ArrayAdapter.
See the following code:

```
((EfficientAdapter)listView1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this will help you.